# How to remove Last word from all the records in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

my table name is RJD (CMTS)
when I do:

```
select CMTS from RJD
```

output:

```
11/24/2020 3:49:23 PM - Padhiyar, Akash  this is approved comment 3  approved
11/24/2020 3:49:11 PM - Padhiyar, Akash  this is reviewing comment 2  Reviewing
11/24/2020 3:48:58 PM - Padhiyar, Akash  this is idea comment 1  Idea
```

I want to remove last word from all the records. in sql.

output should be like this.

```
11/24/2020 3:49:23 PM - Padhiyar, Akash  this is approved comment 3
11/24/2020 3:49:11 PM - Padhiyar, Akash  this is reviewing comment 2 
11/24/2020 3:48:58 PM - Padhiyar, Akash  this is idea comment 1
```

can someone please suggest sql query solution for this.

Comment: Could you not store your data in fields, rather than all in one field which defeats the point in storing it in a database in the first place? e.g. have a ID, Timestamp, User, and Status fields to hold the relevant values?

Comment: _last word from a column_.

Comment: Thank you. It workd.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
select rtrim(left(cmts,
                  len(cmts) - charindex(' ', reverse(cmts))
                 )
           )
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/103429) is a SQL Fiddle.